# Can I expand my ram with my old laptop spare parts?

Tags: memory

I required your help with the following, I have a Lenovo t450 it has a 8gb 2Rx8 PC3L ram my question is if I can add a spare ram I have from my old computer that is a Acer Aspire 4250 witha ram 2gb 1Rx8 PC3.

Answer (score 1):

By its specification,
the Lenovo t450 has on the system board 4GB of non-removeable DDR3L.
It only has a single user-upgradable SO-DIMM slot that can accommodates up to 16GB
of DDR3L (PC3-12800).

Although the RAM looks entirely compatible between your two computers,
I don't see where you can put the additional RAM.
Since you have 8 GB, this means that you already have an additional 4 GB stick
in the user-upgradable slot, with no more empty slots available.

In theory, the T450s can handle up to 20GB of memory if you replace the 4 GB
stick with a larger one, up to 16 GB.

For information only, the
[Crucial website](https://www.crucial.com/)
for modules of 2 GB gives identical specifications for
[Lenovo t450 RAM](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/thinkpad-t450#)
and
[Acer Aspire 4250 RAM](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/acer/aspire-4250-bz637#):

> DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP AND TIME YOU GUYS ARE THE BEST, LOT OF LOVE

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.
PC3L Ram is low voltage (1.35v) while PC3 is not (1.5v) and will thus likely add stability issues to the Lenovo if it is even able to power the RAM in the first place. The 1Rx8 vs 2Rx8 mismatch is less likely to be an issue, but can potentially cause memory stability issues.

Being you already have 8gb of ram the extra 2gb is unlikely to significantly help unless you are already regularly running out of RAM. You probably won't cause any harm to the computer by trying, though it may or may not boot with the ram, apart from the wear and tear of doing so which may be significant, but its unlikely to be worth the effort.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP AND TIME YOU GUYS ARE THE BEST, LOT OF LOVE